# Programmatically name an Excel workbook from VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop, import-from-excel

How do I name an excel workbook that I created using VB.net
Below is my code

```
appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
wbXL = appXL.Workbooks.Add()
```

I wish for the line below to produce set the workbook name but it keeps giving me an error.

```
wbXL.Name = "WorkbookName"
```

I also tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
wbXL.Name().Replace(wbXL.Name, "WorkbookName")
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have to save the workbook first. This will set the property [workbook.name.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.name?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dde-DE%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm199114)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: See [How do I set initial Excel workbook name?](https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/602857-how-do-i-set-initial-excel-workbook-name)

Comment: @Storax, the workbook.name is always giving me the red underlining. How do I overcome that before I use wbXL.Saved?

Comment: @ashleedawg, the responses to the question in the string you sent was inconclusive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Storax for the pointer. I was able to come up with this

```
wbXL.SaveAs(Filename:= "WorkBookName")
```

I will write a code to look into the directory and delete the file anytime the code re-runs so it doesn't ask to overwrite because it already exits.

Thank you guys a lot